# How to unpack multiple dictionary objects inside list within a row of dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with the below dictionaries within a single list in every row and per row, the list are different sizes with they are of different sizes as below:

```
ID    unnest_column

1     [{'abc': 11, 'def': 1},{'abc': 15, 'def': 1},
     {'abc': 16, 'def': 1},
     {'abc': 17, 'def': 1},
     {'abc': 18, 'def': 1, 'ghi': 'abc'},
     {'abc': 23, 'def': 'xxx', 'def': 1},
     {'abc': 23, 'def': 'xxx', 'def': 2},
     {'abc': 23, 'def': 'xxx', 'def': 4}]


2   [{'abc': 11, 'def': 1}]
```

How do I unpack the dictionaries in the list and make the key values columns?

new df potentially, not sure exactly how it will look, just need keys into columns:

```
id    abc    def     ghi

1       2             3         abc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, from

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['x'] = [[{'QuestionId': 11, 'ResponseId': 1},{'QuestionId': 15, 'ResponseId': 1},
 {'QuestionId': 16, 'ResponseId': 1},
 {'QuestionId': 17, 'ResponseId': 1},
 {'QuestionId': 18, 'ResponseId': 1, 'Value': 'abc'},
 {'QuestionId': 23, 'DataLabel': 'xxx', 'ResponseId': 1},
 {'QuestionId': 23, 'DataLabel': 'xxx', 'ResponseId': 2},
 {'QuestionId': 23, 'DataLabel': 'xxx', 'ResponseId': 4}],
[{'QuestionId': 11, 'ResponseId': 1}]]
```

You can `sum` your lists to aggregate them, and use `DataFrame` constructor

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(df.x.values.sum())


    DataLabel   QuestionId  ResponseId  Value
0   NaN         11          1           NaN
1   NaN         15          1           NaN
2   NaN         16          1           NaN
3   NaN         17          1           NaN
4   NaN         18          1           abc
5   xxx         23          1           NaN
6   xxx         23          2           NaN
7   xxx         23          4           NaN
8   NaN         11          1           NaN
```

If you want to maintain the original indexes, you can build a `inds` list and pass it as arguments to the constructor:

```
inds = [index for _ in ([i] * len(v) for i,v in df.x.iteritems()) for index in _]
pd.DataFrame(df.x.values.sum(), index=inds)

    DataLabel   QuestionId  ResponseId  Value
0   NaN         11          1           NaN
0   NaN         15          1           NaN
0   NaN         16          1           NaN
0   NaN         17          1           NaN
0   NaN         18          1           abc
0   xxx         23          1           NaN
0   xxx         23          2           NaN
0   xxx         23          4           NaN
1   NaN         11          1           NaN
```

Comment: this works. However the dataframe has roughly 30 other rows, could this operation be done in the same dataframe while maintaining the shape? If not no worries I will accept the answer

Comment: this is awesome and way better than using `apply(pd.Series)` and `stack` but with this method, how do keep the id number? is there a way to link this number in your new_df? just a curiosity :)

Comment: @Ben.T there is a way to maintain the IDs :) will edit.

Comment: @RafaelC smart and easy. already upvote so can't do more ^^ but I keep in mind this method :)

Comment: @RafaelC if there are 'nan' in some of the nested objects in the originial dataframe, can your code still work?