# How to unpack multiple dictionary objects inside list within a row of dataframe with NaNs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with the below dictionaries within a single list in every row and per row, the list are different sizes with they are of different sizes as below:

```
ID    unnest_column

1     [{'abc': 11, 'def': 1},{'abc': 15, 'def': 1},
     {'abc': 16, 'def': 1},
     {'abc': 17, 'def': 1},
     {'abc': 18, 'def': 1, 'ghi': 'abc'},
     {'abc': 23, 'def': 'xxx', 'def': 1},
     {'abc': 23, 'def': 'xxx', 'def': 2},
     {'abc': 23, 'def': 'xxx', 'def': 4}]


2   NaN
3   [{'abc': 11, 'def': 1}]
```

How do I unpack the dictionaries in the list and make the key values columns?

new df potentially, not sure exactly how it will look, just need keys into columns:

```
id    abc    def     ghi

1       2    3       abc
```

I got this code from another question I asked:

```
inds = [index for _ in ([i] * len(v) for i,v in df.x.iteritems()) for index in _]
pd.DataFrame(df.x.values.sum(), index=inds)
```

but the issue is that the NaNs are causing the second line to fail and I get error:

```
can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

If I change the data type to string of the column in question, I get the below error for the second line of code:

```
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!
```

If I only run the inside of the second line, inside the parenthesis, I get error:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: I have 0 idea as to the output you desire

Comment: Can't help till I understand that

Comment: @RushabhMehta this is the orginial question. I have to unpack another column but have nans in it, not allowing me to unpack. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528643/how-to-unpack-multiple-dictionary-objects-inside-list-within-a-row-of-dataframe/51528720?noredirect=1#comment90026114_51528720

Comment: Yea obviously it wouldn't let you unpack, what do you expect the program to do with the NaNs?

Comment: Again, you need to post your desired output for this example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unpack multiple dictionary objects inside list within a row of dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51528643/how-to-unpack-multiple-dictionary-objects-inside-list-within-a-row-of-dataframe)

Comment: @RushabhMehta its not a duplicate question if I am asking how to take care of Nans. desired output is aboce

Comment: Your "desired output" is a one line dataframe that doesn't explain what you want to do with the NaNs...I don't get why this is so confusing for you

Comment: @RushabhMehta why is this so confusing for you? look at the question I linked, do I really need to make the output complete? If you are commenting on this question shouldnt you be able to take the sample output and extrapolate? All I am asking is how do i handle nans from my previous question.

Comment: "abc"  and 'def' are NaN technically. Do you mean np.nan? We can infer all day long what you mean, but providing a complete question may be better. Why are you being so difficult in providing the desired output? The time you spend debating someone who was trying to help you could have been spent adding more lines to your desired output...